# Strange error when plotting ROC curves using ROCR package

Tags: r

I try to create a simple ROC curve doing the following:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf)
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
  Error in UseMethod("prop_type") : 
  no applicable method for 'prop_type' applied to an object of class "performance"
```

Any thoughts what might cause this?

This is my `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
  [1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
  [1] ggvis_0.4.2  dplyr_0.4.3  ROCR_1.0-7   gplots_3.0.1 FNN_1.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_0.12.4        gtools_3.5.0       digest_0.6.9       assertthat_0.1     mime_0.4          
[6] bitops_1.0-6       R6_2.1.2           xtable_1.8-2       DBI_0.3.1          magrittr_1.5      
[11] KernSmooth_2.23-15 lazyeval_0.1.10    gdata_2.17.0       tools_3.2.3        shiny_0.13.2      
[16] httpuv_1.3.3       parallel_3.2.3     caTools_1.17.1     htmltools_0.3.5
```

Comment: I can't replicate. This code works fine on my machine. Please post your `sessionInfo()` results into the question.

Comment: @Andrie just added it

Comment: What if you `detach("package:ggvis")` (and maybe the other packages) before plotting? I.e. start with a clean session?

Comment: I agree with @lukeA. Start in a clean session and see if the problem still occurs. If it doesn't, then you know there is interference with another package. Narrow down the problem by loading your other packages one-by-one, until the problem recurs. If you still can't trace the problem, then please post a reproducible example, i.e. an example that throws the error in a clean R session.